# How to say "spoil"

Tags: translation, words

For example

> He spoiled the joke by putting the punchline in the title.

or

> I haven't finished watching it so don't spoil the plot!

All I can find in the dictionary for "spoil" is of food/physical objects (break down) and of people (to pamper).

My best guess is バラせる but I'm probably way off base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ばれる](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) (intransitive verb), [ばらす](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B0%E3%82%89%E3%81%99) (transitive verb), or more specifically, [ネタばれ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%83%AC) (noun, sometimes suru-verb).

> - 彼はタイトルにオチを入れてジョークをばらしてしまった。(literally)
> - タイトルでオチがばれてしまっている。
> - そのギャグはタイトルでネタバレになってしまっている。
> - まだ見てないから、ストーリーをばらさないで！
> - まだ見てないから、ネタバレしないで！

ばらせる is the potential form of ばらす.